Chart shade of the area between two lines only when one is above the other in Excel
I'm trying to get a chart in Excel similar to:

where when my real values are under the plan there is a red area (i don't care when the real values are better than the plan). I've managed to get this:

But as you can see there are given that Excel does not know the data when one curve passes under the other, how can i fix this?


Since you are not providing any data, I constructed here some simple monthly plan vs. actual data stored in the range A1:F13



Month
Plan
Actual
Reference
Positive
Negative




1
400
510
400
110
0


2
350
420
350
70
0


3
438
490
438
52
0


4
320
390
320
70
0


5
432
425
432
0
-7


6
436
350
436
0
-86


7
395
320
395
0
-75


8
369
300
369
0
-69


9
410
420
410
10
0


10
330
400
330
70
0


11
426
500
426
74
0


12
398
450
398
52
0



"Month", "Plan", and "Actual" are simply some mock data (i.e., your raw data). "Reference" is simply a duplication of your "Plan" values, and "Positive" and "Negative" are simply the positive and negative deviations between actual and plan. For this, I use an IF() function, with the formulas in cell E2 and F2 being: =IF(C2>B2,C2-B2,0) and =IF(C2<=B2,C2-B2,0). That means if actual is larger than plan collect it in positive and otherwise collect it in negative.
Selecte your data in the range A1_F13 and insert a line chart. This will look as follows:

Select the chart > Chart Design > Change Chart Type > Combo and change it to the following types:

And now simply set your colors according to your needs. The final chart looks then as follows:

